# Offset of bnez in RISC-V program

Tags: assembly, addressing, assembler, risc-v

I came across a question about assembly that I was confused on.

We are given the following table for addresses and instructions:
[image]

The question says: replace the labels of PC-relative targets with their immediate values. What is the
offset value of bnez at address 0x20? Write your answer in decimal.

I put -6, since if bnez, it goes to loop, which is at 0x14. However, the answer given is -12.

How did they get that?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you say you 'came across' this question, do you mean this is homework?

Comment: 0x20 and 0x14 are hexadecimal

Comment: Translate both addresses into decimal and try again.